# PHP contact form submit button opening index html

Tags: php, wordpress, html, forms, templates

I am making a **`custom contact`** form via **`html5 and php`**. I have got the form looking like I want and am trying to check if the values entered in the fields are working. I am `print_r($_POST)` to display the `arrays`.

When clicking the `submit button` it is `not displaying the array` but `opening the index.html file` instead?

The code is as follows...

Contact template calling in the form php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: contact
*/
get_header();

if (have_posts()) : 
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      get_template_part('form');
   endwhile; 
else: 
   echo '<p>No Content found</p>';
endif;
?>
</body>
     Template part form.php (html layout)

    <?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
    <div class='grey'>    
        <div class="container-contact">  
            <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <div class='contact-logo'></div>
              <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" tabindex="2" >
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
              </fieldset>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the following form being called in **`form.php = (form_process.php)`**

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);

    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";
    $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

    //form is submitted with POST method
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
      } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
      }

      if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
          $message_body = '';
          unset($_POST['submit']);
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
              $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
          }

          $to = 'vladi@clevertechie.com';
          $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
          if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
              $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
              $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
          }
      }

    }

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
```

Why is the submit button opening `index.html`?

I would make a snippet but dont know how to do this with multiple templates being called in?

Thanks.

UPDATE OF form_process.php file after removing the invalid variables where there are no longer input boxes holding those values

```
        print_r($_POST);

        // define variables and set to empty values
        $name_error = $email_error = "";
        $name = $email = $message = "";

        //form is submitted with POST method
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $name_error = "Name is required";
          } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
          }

          if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $email_error = "Email is required";
          } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
              $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
          }

          if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $message = "";
          } else {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
          }

          if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' ){
              $message_body = '';
              unset($_POST['submit']);
              foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                  $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
              }

              $to = 'info@devonfoodmovement.com';
              $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
              if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
                  $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
                  $name = $email = $message = '';
              }
          }

        }

        function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
```

Comment: change `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` from action to `form_process.php` full path.

Comment: thank you worked a charm. So am i right in guessing that $_POST calls the main page not the relevant template to look for as this was bastardised off a single page tutorial?

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` just finds the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. - meaning, if you use it on index.html - it will return /index.html

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan it only works when no info put in boxes? when i put name email and message it loads the design for the index but remains with the url /contact ? and the form disappears?

Comment: and where you want to redirect after submitting?

Comment: i want the html from form.php to be showing and it is not showing that but the html from index.html but is keeping the url /devonfoodmovement/contact/ in the address bar? Basically i want the form to show until the email has been validated and sent then return the form with the your message has been sent message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in your template file's form action, use full path to your `form_process.php` file.

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns:

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the
>   document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the
>   address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php.

**Edit:**

Here is some solution for you to not redirects to another page:

*Template part form.php (html layout):*

```
<?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
<div class='grey'>
    <div class="container-contact">
        <form id="contact" method="post">
            <div class='contact-logo'></div>
            <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name1" autofocus>
                <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" tabindex="2" >
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

*`form_process.php` file:*

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'vladi@clevertechie.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
            $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
        }
    }

}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why this has been downvoted? ('-' )

Comment: when downvoting, then it'll be nice to explain why?

Comment: I didnt downvote? Did you see my last comment on the post above?

Comment: yes, I know, that its not you. And I dont mind to downvote my answers. I just want to understand **why**

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan have you seen my latest edit of the form_process.php I cant help but feel that the validations using $_POST in form_process.php are redirecting the page somewhere else?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan thanks ever so much, sorted it out immediately